# Testing component in NativeScript Angular2 app

Tags: unit-testing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm having issues doing a very simple component test in a NativeScript Angular 2 application. I can't seem to just call "new Component()" and then test it like was shown in [this](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/unit-testing-a-nativescript-angular-2-application-nic-raboy/522) test example. I'm trying an implementation of the Angular 2 TestBed in order to gain access to the component. This doesn't appear to be working either. Has anybody run into a similar problem or have any experience with this?

Component under test:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "links",
    templateUrl: "./components/links/links.component.html"
})

export class LinksComponent {
    test = "test";

    public constructor() {

    }
}
```

Test:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { LinksComponent } from "../../components/links/links.component";
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe("Links Component", () => {

    let comp: LinksComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LinksComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ LinksComponent ],
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LinksComponent);

        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it("will pass because this is a silly test", () => {
        expect(comp.test).toEqual("test");
    })
});
```

Log output:

```
NativeScript / 10.3 (10.3; iPhone)  ../../tests/components/links.spec.js at line 0 FAILED
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Zone
NativeScript / 10.3 (10.3; iPhone): Executed 1 of 0 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0 seNativeScript / 10.3 (10.3; iPhone): Executed 1 of 0 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.008 secs / 0 secs)
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:258:24: NSUTR: completeAck
May 11 16:16:43 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:90:28: NSUTR-socket.io: io server disconnect
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:151:24: NSUTR: disregarding second execution
Test run failed.
```

Comment: Not officially supported still you can take a look at the discussion in the linked issue for possible solutions by community members https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/479#issuecomment-265966999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK TestBed does not work on NativeScript Angular.
To mock components you need to instance them with `new`, resolving each dependency.

You should study this [repository](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/tree/master/tests/app/tests) to be able to do some unit testing on NativeScript.

Comment: You are correct. I did see that some users made it work, but this seems like a better approach. At first, I was trying this and specifying only TypeScript files in my karma.config. I got a screen full of errors. As soon as I removed the TypeScript files and added the transpiled JS files the tests will run properly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: It seems some wrappers have been added for the version 6.
See https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/commit/52f3ec6047445deb0a53b7e997393d4c7f2d1b2e
and a snippet: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/tests/app/tests/snippets.ts